# Refresh Kendo Grid with a new filter (ServerSide)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have some external elements on my angular application page that I want to use to filter the grid. Unfortunately I am not sure how to do this. My filters need to be applied dynamically to the grid and sent to the backend as serverFiltering is set to true.

What I have so far: This refreshes the grid, but doesn't send the new filter to the backend. It seems to be sending the default initial parameters. I have checked getFilter and it returns the necessary filter object.

```
$scope.fromDateChanged = function ()
{
    $scope.grid.dataSource.filter = getFilter();
    $scope.grid.dataSource.read();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I had to simply pass the filter object into the filter function of the grid. read() is not required to be called. Hope this helps somebody.

```
$scope.fromDateChanged = function ()
{
    $scope.grid.dataSource.filter(getFilter());
};
```